# Editing Spec file in RPM

Tags: rpm, dependencies

I'm trying to edit a spec file which always fails when I try to install it on other computer using RPM. I'm using CentOS. Here is the error.

```
error: Failed dependencies:
perl(ActsUtil) is needed by my_program
perl(ParseBishop) is needed by my_program
```

Both these 2 files are dependencies for the RPM. The thing is, these 2 files are actually provided inside the RPM package. Both these files are .pm file and located inside `/opt/mysoftware/bin`. I know it can be solved using `rpm - ivh --nodeps mysoftware`. But I don't prefer to use that method. So, I tried fixing the spec file. Here are some of the code that I've tried.

1st try

```
Summary:....
Name:..
Version:..
....
....
Provides: perl(ParseBishop), perl(ActsUtil)
...
...
%install
...
...
%changelog
```

2nd try

```
Summary:....
Name:..
Version:..
....
....
Provides: ParseBishop, ActsUtil
...
...
%install
...
...
%changelog
```

3rd try

```
Summary:....
Name:..
Version:..
....
....
Provides: ParseBishop.pm, ActsUtil.pm
...
...
%install
...
...
%changelog
```

4th try

```
Summary:....
Name:..
Version:..
....
....
Provides: /opt/mysoftware/bin/ParseBishop, /opt/mysoftware/bin/ActsUtil
...
...
%install
...
...
%changelog
```

Am I doing the "Provides" command wrong? Or my approach in solving the issue is already wrong?

Comment: You may try adding `AutoReq: 0`, `Autoprov: 0` to disable dependency requirements and removing both `Requires: depend1`, `Provides: depend1` lines. Ref: http://rpm5.org/docs/api/specfile.html P.S. I haven't test it before.

Comment: @MohdFikrie If you have found the solution, please consider answering your own question and marking the answer accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was my Provides are in the wrong area. It is suppose to be at the top of the code.

```
Summary:....
Name:..
Version:..
Provides: perl(ParseBishop), perl(ActsUtil)
...
...
%install
...
...
%changelog
```

To verify this. I have used  `rpm -qp --provides mysoftware.rpm` inside the built folder. It will display what are provided from my packages.Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
rpm -i --nodeps my_program.rpm
```

would skip any dependency prolems.

Comment: Yes..it can be run with that. But I prefer not to use that command. I would like to fix the .spec file instead.

Comment: It's still a working command, but allright, see you found the solution using what you wanted in the comments

Answer (score 0):

#### PreReq?

I wonder if you need to list them as `PreReqs`?

> Prereqs are different from requires only in that a PreReq is
>   guaranteed to be installed before the package that contains the
>   PreReq. PreReq's are used only to order packages, otherwise PreReq's
>   are exactly the same as a Requires: dependency.

*source: http://rpm5.org/docs/api/dependencies.html*

#### Example

```
PreReq: perl(ActsUtil), perl(ParseBishop)
```

#### Requires

If those Perl modules are in fact required for this RPM to install then wouldn't they need to be on the `Requires` line and not `Provides`?

#### Example

```
Requires: perl(ParseBishop), perl(ActsUtil)
```

#### Just files?

If they're just .pm files that you're providing as part of the installation then these files shouldn't need to be listed anywhere except in in the RPMs install & manifest.

Other RPMs that depend on them would then just Require this RPM.

Comment: No its not. It is also needed after installation because some files are dependent on that file. Somehow the rpm cannot recognise the file is already provided inside the package.

Comment: @MohdFikrie - are the Perl modules actually in RPMs then or ar they just .pm files you're trying to include with this RPM? If they're just .pm files then you just need to include them in the installation manfiest, no?